# Azure k8s pods to cluster external communication via internal IPs

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am migrating from GCP to Azure. My use case is simple: I have a k8s cluster running some web crawlers which needs to talk to Elastic and Cassandra clusters (not in the k8s cluster) using internal IPs. All of these components can be in the same Azure Region (e.g: East US). I understand from this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-dev/Gp2QBEcuTwI) that VNET peering is the way to go.

This solution did not work for me. I am still unable to reach my Cass/ES cluster from the pods. I believe this solution is outdated, is there some other approach to accomplish this, that I am missing ?

Comment: vnet peering should do the trick for you. can your master ping\reach those nodes?

Comment: The nodes can but the pods can't even with peering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Azure **route table** to achieve that, then we can ping pod IP address out of your k8s Vnet.

I have answered your another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46277845/k8s-pods-unable-to-reach-external-vm-via-internal-ip/46291889#46291889), please check it.

If you would like further assistance, please let me know:)

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer on my other post/question. This solved my issue.